# Dynamically apply different y-axes to data in a jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I'm trying to create a jqplot with multiple lines plotted on it, where the number of data series depends on user input.

Now I want to use two different y-axes for certain kinds of results, but the jqplot documentation only shows how to assign different y-axis to series in a static way.

Is there a dynamic solution?

Answer (score 0):

you will need to change the option string when ever you need to have different y axises, But still you will need to re draw the chart as well..